# Script to determine the outcome(s) of any number of dice rolls

Tags: python, game, python-2.x, dice

I think this code has far to many if else clauses and not enough abstraction via functions. I would like to break the code down into a series of small functions, or methods if i decide to go OOP, but I'm not sure of the best way to do so. If you brilliant Pythonista's could guide me in the write direction I would appreciate it.

Here is the GitHub repo if you would like to fork it [repo](https://github.com/andlee90/random_di.git)

```
'''
script to determine the outcome(s) of any number of dice rolls
By Andrew Smith (2015)
'''

from random import randint

def dice_roller(dice, rolls, sides):
    '''
    Add doc string here.
    '''
    show_di = '|   |'
    show_di_1 = '| * |'
    show_di_2 = '|* *|'
    show_di_3 = '|***|'
    show_di_t = ' ___ '
    show_di_b = ' --- '
    roll_counter = 0
    di_counter = 0

    while roll_counter < rolls:
        roll_counter += 1
        di_counter = 0
        print " "

        while di_counter < dice:
            di_counter += 1
            num_side = randint(1, sides)
            print "Roll %r, Di %r: %r" % (roll_counter, di_counter, num_side)
            if num_side <= 6: # print di symbol if di is six-sided
                if num_side == 1:
                    print show_di_t
                    print show_di_1
                    print show_di
                    print show_di_b
                elif num_side == 2:
                    print show_di_t
                    print show_di_1
                    print show_di_1
                    print show_di_b
                elif num_side == 3:
                    print show_di_t
                    print show_di_1
                    print show_di_2
                    print show_di_b
                elif num_side == 4:
                    print show_di_t
                    print show_di_2
                    print show_di_2
                    print show_di_b
                elif num_side == 5:
                    print show_di_t
                    print show_di_2
                    print show_di_3
                    print show_di_b
                elif num_side == 6:
                    print show_di_t
                    print show_di_3
                    print show_di_3
                    print show_di_b
    print " "
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

TITLE = """
 __________________
| Dice Roller v1.1 |
| by Andrew Smith  |
|__________________|
"""

MENU = """
Enter the number of dice to roll, the number
of rolls, and the number of sides per di in the
following format: #dice #rolls #sides

--- or ---

Select from the following presets:

a. 3 man attack (Risk)
b. 2 man attack or defend (Risk)
c. 1 man attack or defend (Risk)

--- or ---

Type 'menu' to repeat this menu

--- or ---

Type 'quit' to quit
        """

def main():
    '''
    Explain this function.
    '''
    print TITLE
    print MENU
    again = 0

    while again != 1: # prompts the user until 'quit' is entered
        roll_choice = raw_input("> ")
        if roll_choice.isalpha(): # if input starts with a letter
            if roll_choice == 'a':
                dice_roller(3, 1, 6)
            elif roll_choice == 'b':
                dice_roller(2, 1, 6)
            elif roll_choice == 'c':
                dice_roller(1, 1, 6)
            elif roll_choice == 'menu':
                print MENU
            elif roll_choice == 'quit':
                again = 1
            else:
                print "Invalid choice.\n"

        elif roll_choice[0].isdigit(): # if input starts with a number
            choices = roll_choice.split()
            size = len(choices)
            if size == 3:
                one = int(choices[0])
                two = int(choices[1])
                three = int(choices[2])
                dice_roller(one, two, three)
            else:
                print "Invalid Choice.\n"
        else:
            print "Invalid choice.\n"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `while counter < N: counter += 1` is something of a red flag  :)  why not a `for` loop?

Answer (score 4):

**Use unpacking**

```
        choices = roll_choice.split()
        size = len(choices)
        if size == 3:
            one = int(choices[0])
            two = int(choices[1])
            three = int(choices[2])
            dice_roller(one, two, three)
        else:
            print "Invalid Choice.\n"
```

Becomes:

```
dice_roller( * map(int, roll_choice.split()) )
```

Adding error handling it is:

```
 try:
     dice_roller( * map(int, roll_choice.split()) )
 except Exception as e:
     print("Invalid choice:" + e)
```

The `*` operator just goes from a list to free floating arguments and is called the unpacking operator. You use it to pass a list as argument to a function that takes separate arguments.

**Naming in full**

You should write the names of your variables in full to make them more understandable at first glance. `show` may be omitted. For example:

- `show_di_1` ➡ `dice_1`
- `show_di_b` ➡ `dice_bottom`

**A dictionary**

A dictionary will allow you to avoid the first if elif chain easily. How is left as an exercise for the reader.

Answer (score 2):

Here is some general style comments, related to the previously given advice of reading and adhering to [PEP8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/):

- *Use docstrings, but let them have meaning* – To have docstrings and comments can help understanding code, but stuff like 'explaing this function' or 'add doc string here' is a little annoying
- *You have many good variable and function names* – You've found that in Python one uses `snake_case` for variable and function names, and that is good. You've also picked up on `CONSTANTS` using capital letters.

  You could hovewer move your constants to a group closer to the top of the file. Normal sequence is typical: imports, constants, functions (and/or classes), main function called by the `if __name__ ...` construct, like you already do.
- *Change to newer style print function* – From Python 3 you'll have to use [print as a function](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html?highlight=print#print), but one can start doing this already to make the transistion easier. On the same tangent one can start using the new style of [print formatting](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatspec). This changes you print statements to stuff like `print('Roll {}, Dice {}: {}'.format(roll_counter, di_counter, num_side))`
- *Make functions instead of big `if ... elif` chains* – Within `dice_roller` it would be better to extract all the `print show_...` into a separate function. Whenever you find your self copy-pasting code, think functions. In this case you take it all the like in [my question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/111337/78136) (inspired by this question), or you do a simpler variant like:

  ```
  def print_dice(roll):
      no_eyes = '|   |'
      one_eye = '| * |'
      two_eyes = '|* *|'
      three_eyes = '|***|'
      top_line = ' ___ '
      bottom_line = ' --- '

      print(top_line)
      # First line
      if roll == 6:
          print(three_eyes)
      elif roll >= 4:
          print(two_eyes)
      else:
          print(one_eye)

      # Second line
      if roll == 1:
          print(no_eyes)
      elif roll = 2:
          print(one_eye)
      elif roll == 6:
         print(three_eyes)
      else: 
          print(two_eyes)

      print(bottom_line)
  ```

  Especially note how I moved the printing of the top and bottom line out on the outside of the `if` blocks, and that I also consolidated the rolls which prints the same number of eyes. And that I've written out the variable names to `two_eyes` instead of `show_di_2`. The latter kind of implicates that the variable is showing something, which *could* be true if it was a function, but not as a variable.
- *Avoid flag variable, if possible* – Sometimes you need to do stuff like `while again != 1`, but the first change would be to actually use `while again` where normally `again = True`, but even better here would be to use `while True:`, and then do `break` when `roll_choice == 'quit'`.
- *Avoiding one-time temporary variables* – Two examples in your code, is the `again` variable, but another one is the `size = len(choices)` followed by `if size == 3:`. It could be good to do the `len()` once, if you use the result multiple times, but if only used once, it is usually better to be explicit and only do the `if len(choices) == 3:`. (Even better is to use the alternate unpacking suggested in another answer)